# error handling aspnet core 2.2 razor pages

Tags: c#, razor, error-handling, middleware, razor-pages

I have a very simple exception that is handled by the default error page generated by VS2017 for razor pages .net core.
The error page shows with a exception error - is there any way I can show a custom error something like "Error in command try again"

```
     try
      {

      var interenet = "nc -w 5 -z 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'ok' || echo 'error'".Bash();

        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
           {
               _logger.LogError(
                            0, ex2,
                            "An exception was thrown attempting " +
                            "to execute the error handler.");

                    throw new Exception(ex2.Message);
   }
```

Error page model

```
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
    {
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

        public void OnGet()
        {
            RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        }
    }
```

Startup class I have added

```
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` is designed to intercept *unhandled* exceptions. You are handling your exception, but then throwing another, creating an new unhandled exception and thereby forcing the configured error page to be shown by the middleware. I would add a public string property to the page in which the error happens, and set that to whatever error message you want in the `catch` block, thereby handling the exception and not invoking the custom error page:

```
public class YourPageModel : PageModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public void OnGet() // or OnPost, whichever
    {
        try
        {
            var internet = "nc -w 5 -z 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'ok' || echo 'error'".Bash();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            _logger.LogError(0, ex2, "An exception was thrown attempting " +
                            "to execute the error handler.");
            ErrorMessage = "Error in command try again";
        }
    }
}
```

Add `<p>@Model.ErrorMessage</p>` somewhere on the content page that belongs to the PageModel where this exception is raised.

Comment: thanks very useful - is there someway to implement this so I dont have to have try/catch everywhere?